# postgres json_populate_recordset not working as expected

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table called `slices` with some simple json objects that looks like this:

```
id | payload                               | metric_name
---|---------------------------------------|------------
1  | {"a_percent":99.97,"c_percent":99.97} | metric_c
2  | {"a_percent":98.37,"c_percent":97.93} | metric_c
```

many records of this. I am trying to get this:

```
a_percent | c_percent
----------|----------
99.97     | 99.97
98.37     | 97.93
```

I am creating the type and using `json_populate_recordset` along with `json_agg` in the following fashion:

```
CREATE TYPE c_history AS(
    "a_percent" NUMERIC(5, 2),
    "c_percent" NUMERIC(5, 2)
);

SELECT * FROM
    json_populate_recordset(
        NULL :: c_history,
        (
            SELECT json_agg(payload::json) FROM slices
            WHERE metric_name = 'metric_c'
        )
    );
```

The clause `select json_agg(...)` by itself produces a nice array of json objects, as expected:

```
[{"a_percent":99.97,"c_percent":99.97}, {"a_percent":98.37,"c_percent":97.93}]
```

But when I run it inside `json_populate_recordset`, I get `Error : ERROR:  must call json_populate_recordset on an array of objects`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2ccd68/1

Comment: Sorry everyone. The problem was in my data. Some of the records contained an object, some an array. This is why i was getting errors both ways. I think you for your time and apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variant of @TimBiegeleisen's solution with the function `json_populate_record()` used in a `from` clause:

```
select id, r.* 
from slices, 
lateral json_populate_record(null::c_history, payload) r;
```

See [rextester](http://rextester.com/UIAN27825) or [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dce10/1).

Comment: Once I fixed my data to be consistent with my question, this answer worked as written. Thank you @klin.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `json_agg`, since it appears you want to get the set of `a_percent` and `c_percent` values for each `id` in a separate record.  Rather just call `json_populate_recordset` as follows:

```
SELECT id, (json_populate_record(null::c_history, payload)).* FROM slices
```

Comment: `(json_populate_record(null::c_history, payload)).*` (not `json_populate_recordset`)

Comment: Pretty sure that complains about it needing to be an array of objects, but I'll try it.

Comment: @avguchenko If it doesn't work, I'll go ahead and delete it.

Comment: @klin `json_populate_record` complains `cannot call json_populate_record on an array`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this statement complains `cannot call json_populate_recordset on an object`